# Graph Theory | How we can prove a graph is connected by looking at the degrees of two non-adjacent vertices?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I would love any help given with a problem I'm facing with my homework:

Let $G(V,E)$ an arbitrary, undirected graph. I need to prove that for every two non-adjacent vertices that hold $\deg(u)+\deg(v)\ge \mid V\mid-1$ then $G$ is a connected graph.

can someone direct me to any prove strategy for this claim?
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $u,v \in V$ are nonadjacent nodes with $ u \neq v$ and $\deg(u) + \deg(v) \geq \lvert V \rvert - 1$. Then $\lvert V \setminus \{u,v\} \rvert = \lvert V \rvert -2$.

Denote by $N_G(v)$ the neighborhood of $v$. If there is a node $w \in N_G(u) \cap N_G(v)$, then there is a path from $u$ to $v$ ($uw, wv$).

If there is no node $w \in N_G(u) \cap N_G(v)$, then the two neighborhoods of $u$ and $v$ are disjoint, thus we arrive at the contradiction $$\deg(u) + \deg(v) = \lvert N_G(u) \rvert + \lvert N_G(v) \rvert = \lvert N_G(u) \cup N_G(v) \rvert \leq \lvert V \rvert - 2$$ (because neither $u$ nor $v$ is in the union).